# How to find path for on submit text box

Tags: javascript, html, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm trying to reference a URL in a local application and am having difficultly finding the correct path to reference. 
It uses a value that the website transforms into another value for the page requested.

The main URL is http://exac.broadinstitute.org/

My inputs contain variations of ***rs113488022*** , which the website will turn to a variant

http://exac.broadinstitute.org/variant/7-140453136-A-T

Unfortunately I do not have this variant value to pass directly,and am looking for the path of the on submit action from the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes, that is some horrible HTML code.

But if you inspect the input element you find that the form has a simple action `/awesome`, and the input’s name is `query`. As a consequence, you can simply perform a GET on the following URI:

```
http://exac.broadinstitute.org/awesome?query=rs113488022
```

Be prepared to process redirects, because the above will give you an HTTP response of `302 FOUND` with a redirect location (which is the URI you found).